# Identifying duplicated values including the first value in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
ROW  ID   DATE  
1    1    09/20/2014
2    1    09/21/2014
3    1    09/22/2014
4    1    09/22/2014
5    2    09/19/2014
6    2    09/20/2014
7    2    09/21/2014
8    2    09/21/2014
9    2    09/21/2014
10   3    09/18/2014
11   3    09/19/2014
12   3    09/20/2014
13   3    09/20/2014
```

I want to create a column FL to identify repeating dates by ID , I know duplicated() will identify subsequent repeating values but I also want to identify the first value before it starts to repeat

My data should look like:

```
ROW  ID   DATE         FL
1    1    09/20/2014    0
2    1    09/21/2014    0
3    1    09/22/2014    1
4    1    09/22/2014    1
5    2    09/19/2014    0
6    2    09/20/2014    0
7    2    09/21/2014    1
8    2    09/21/2014    1
9    2    09/21/2014    1
10   3    09/18/2014    0 
11   3    09/19/2014    0
12   3    09/20/2014    1
13   3    09/20/2014    1
```

So for each ID the non-repeating dates get a FL value of 0 and repeating dates get a FL value of 1. It would be great if you could help me with the R code to do this. Thank you.

### edit

here a dput of the data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
              DATE = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
              .Label = c("9/18/2014", "9/19/2014", "9/20/2014", "9/21/2014", "9/22/2014"), 
                        class = "factor")), 
              .Names = c("ID", "DATE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Try `with(dat, ave(as.numeric(factor(DATE)), ID, FUN=function(x) duplicated(x)|duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE)))`

Comment: I tried the following way :for(i in 1:nrow(totaldata)){totaldata$FL <- ifelse(totaldata$DATE[i]==totaldata$DATE[i+1],1,0)}

Comment: However, I got NA values in the FL column, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this using `data.table` package:

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[,FL := (duplicated(DATE) | duplicated(DATE, fromLast = TRUE))*1,ID]
    ID      DATE FL
 1:  1 9/20/2014  0
 2:  1 9/21/2014  0
 3:  1 9/22/2014  1
 4:  1 9/22/2014  1
 5:  2 9/19/2014  0
 6:  2 9/20/2014  0
 7:  2 9/21/2014  1
 8:  2 9/21/2014  1
 9:  2 9/21/2014  1
10:  3 9/18/2014  0
11:  3 9/19/2014  0
12:  3 9/20/2014  1
13:  3 9/20/2014  1
```

Or In base R ( using @akrun propsition):

```
transform(dat, ave(as.numeric(factor(DATE)), ID, 
           FUN=function(x) duplicated(x)|duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE)))
```

Comment: I tried the following way :for(i in 1:nrow(totaldata)){totaldata$FL <- ifelse(totaldata$DATE[i]==totaldata$DATE[i+1],1,0)}

Comment: However, I got NA values in the FL column, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want me to paste output generated when I run the command dput(mydataframename)  ?

Comment: @AG I tried adding that in the question, however, it is not allowing me to save the edi. I'm posting it here, please take a look:  structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), DATE = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("9/18/2014", "9/19/2014", "9/20/2014", 
"9/21/2014", "9/22/2014"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"DATE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

Comment: Thank you for adding it. Going back to my question, why am I getting NA values in the FL column?

Comment: @VineetGoti did you copy and paste the code? I just use your structure...it should give you the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, here's one crude way of solving this problem.

```
# your original data frame
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
         DATE = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
           .Label = c("9/18/2014", "9/19/2014", "9/20/2014", "9/21/2014", "9/22/2014"), 
           class = "factor")), 
         .Names = c("ID", "DATE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))

# glue the columns to avoid need of grouping by ID first
dat2 <- paste(dat$ID, dat$DATE, sep='/')
# alternatively, you can use following for string comparison, if needed.
# dat2<-paste(as.character(dat$ID),as.character(dat$DATE),sep='/')

# create a lookup table for counts of each ID+DATE combo
lookup<-table(dat2)

# add a column based on counts. If count is 1 then ID+DATE is not duplicated.
dat$FL <- sapply(dat2,FUN = function(x) { if (lookup[x] == 1) 0 else 1})

# output
print(dat)
```

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
   ID      DATE FL
1   1 9/20/2014  0
2   1 9/21/2014  0
3   1 9/22/2014  1
4   1 9/22/2014  1
5   2 9/19/2014  0
6   2 9/20/2014  0
7   2 9/21/2014  1
8   2 9/21/2014  1
9   2 9/21/2014  1
10  3 9/18/2014  0
11  3 9/19/2014  0
12  3 9/20/2014  1
13  3 9/20/2014  1
```

There are more sophisticated ways to do this, and `table()` has its limitations, but for most part, this is simple, easy to read, and should do the job for you.

Comment: Or you could use `unname((rep(lookup, lookup)>1)+0)`

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` + `magrittr` alternative:

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(ID, DATE) %>% 
    mutate(FL = ifelse(n() > 1, 1, 0))
```

A little drawback: it will result in 1 for every duplicated date, not for only the latest. See if it is an inconvenience.